# In a node.js web app, is the only way for the client to communicate with the server through url routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, routes, client-server

I know using the Rest API the client can communicate with the backend anytime using URL routes. On page load you can use the route directly, and without reloading the page you can use ajax request. They both use URL routes to make a request to the server and the server handles it.

But is there any other way the client in a node.js web app communicates with the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily setup WebSocket communication in node, using http://socket.io/ and communicate in that way as well.

Comment: ah I see, so with socket you can call a function directly on the server right? Any downside to using sockets vs routes?

Comment: You can send an event, with optional data to server, and call function when you receive that event. Disadvantages would be that it can not work if the user has javascript disabled, and if you have a lot of users connected at same time you might see some performance issues. And advantage over AJAX(since it's closer to that than routing) would be that you are also able to send events and data from server to the client without much pain, and that allows bidirectional communication.